# What is this noise coming from my gas furnace?

Tags: furnace, gas, noise

Whenever I change my air filters in my furnace, I hear a boom noise. The last time I called DEER and they came out and fixed the problem (I can't remember what the part was called that was needed). It happened again, the booming sound, after I changed the filters. What could be causing this problem and how can I get it fixed and never have it happen again, even after changing the filters?

Comment: As you're sliding the filter in, the boom happens? Are you using a sledgehammer to install the filter?

Comment: Could you define DEER, tell us the furnace fuel, post a picture, and try to localize the sound?

Comment: If you hear the boom when the furnace turns on, it could be the furnace sucking the filter against the intake hole. If the filter bracket has a bit of wiggle room, the filter may not sit right against the inlet. When the blower turns on, a low pressure area is created inside the furnace. The higher pressure air in the cold air return rushes to balance the pressure, which forces the filter to slam into the filter frame as it's forced against the inlet.  However, this is all speculation, since you haven't provided enough information to definitively answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no sledgehammers were used, you could be hearing a sheet metal change shape, triggered by temperature.  It will likely be a large flat area of metal somewhere...